# SlackApiError: The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'not_in_channel'}

Tags: python, api, slack

I am trying to post an image to slack with the following piece of code:

```
import slack
from slack import WebClient
client = slack.WebClient(token=XXX)

response = client.files_upload(    
        file = open("credit_temp.jpg","w"),
        channels='#test_pandl'
    )
```

But I have the following error message:

```
SlackApiError: The request to the Slack API failed.
The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'not_in_channel'}
```

Hereunder are the bot token scopes:

The bot scope token had every access possible

any idea what is happening?

Comment: Maybe add the bot to the channel?

Comment: you need to go to the channel and invite the bot/app

/invite @BOT_NAME